# Interpretation of polar derivative and apolar polynomials

Tags: polynomials, intuition

If $f(x)$ is a degree $n$ polynomial and $b \in \mathbb{C}$ is a complex number, then the *polar derivative* of $f$ with respect to $b$ is defined by
$$D_b f(x) = nf(x) - (x - b)f'(x).$$
Two degree $n$ polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are said to be *apolar* if
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k f^{(k)}(0)g^{(n-k)}(0) = 0,$$
and this is equivalent to
$$D_{b_1}D_{b_2}\cdots D_{b_n} f(x) = 0,$$
where $b_i$ are the roots of $g(x)$ with multiplicity.

I have come across these notions in relation to Grace's Theorem. I am trying to understand the meaning of the polar derivative and to find an interpretation of what it means for two polynomials to be apolar. Pointers to the origins of these notions would also be appreciated.

Comment: It comes from classical invariant theory. First rehomogenize so as to turn you single variable polynomials into binary forms. Then lookup the chapter on Apolarity in the book by Grace and Young https://books.google.com/books?id=NIe4AAAAIAAJ&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Comment: in particular the picture with the conic on page 238. You can also lookup diagram 3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05056 and https://www.projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1258735321

Comment: Chapter I of Dolgachev's *Classical Algebraic Geometry: a modern view* is called "Polarity" and is quite complete (also for multivariate polynomials).

Comment: Thank you for the references!