Motivation for defining polar derivative
The polar derivative of a polynomial $p(z)$ is defined as
$$ D_\alpha p(z):=np(z)+(\alpha -z)p^{\prime}(z) \qquad \alpha\in\mathbb{C}. $$ It is a polynomial of degree $n-1.$ I am new to complex polynomials and complex analysis and I could not think of some motivation behind the need to define this derivative .I would be very obliged if somebody could kindly point ou the context and the motivation behind it along with some resources or links.thank youin advance .

This has been answered already here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/378463/interpretation-of-polar-derivative-and-apolar-polynomials

There is no answer there to this question,so far as I can see

Have you checked the references in the comments?

The motivation (and the word "polar") comes from algebraic geometry. Consider the homogenized polynomial $P(x,y)=y^n p(x/y)$, where $p$ is a complex polynomial of degree $n$. The polar of $P$ with respect to the point $(a:b)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta_{(a:b)}P(x,y) &= a \frac{\partial P}{\partial x}+b \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} \\
&= by^{n-1} \left(np\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)-\left(\frac{x}{y}-\frac{a}{b}\right)p'\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right).
\end{align}
$$
If we dehomogenize this polynomial by setting $y=1$, we find that the polar with respect to a finite point $(a:1)$ is the polar derivative:
$$
\Delta_{(a:1)}P(x,1) = np(x)-(x-a)p'(x) = D_ap(x),
$$
and we also find that the polar with respect to the point at infinity $(1:0)$ is the ordinary derivative:
$$
\Delta_{(1:0)}P(x,1) = p'(x).
$$
Hence we have a nice analogy: the polar derivative $D_a p$ is to a finite point $a \in \mathbb{C}$ as the ordinary derivative $p'$ is to the point $\infty$ of the Riemann sphere.
Here are two books with more information:

Marden, "Geometry of Polynomials," Chapter III
Polya and Szego, "Problems and Theorems in Analysis II," Part V, Chapter 2, §3

